# How can I write DSSIM+MAE loss function for model training

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

How can I write code DSSIM+MAE loss function from formula:

```
                                          Loss = αMAE + (1-α)DSSIM
```

with

```
                             Mean Absolute Error(MAE) = (1/M) * ∑|yi – xi|

                                               DSSIM = 1-SSIM

                    SSIM = (numerator1 * numerator2) / (denominator1 * denominator2)
```

numerator1 = 2 * μ12 + C1   #μ12 = μ1 * μ2

numerator2 = 2 * σ12 + C2

denominator1 = μ1_sq + μ2_sq + C1

denominator2 = σ1_sq + σ2_sq + C2

---

where α is a trade-off parameter between MAE and DSSIM,

M is the total number of pixels in the image,

μ is the mean value of the image,

σ is the standard variation of the image, and σx,y is the covariance of x and y two images. c1 and c2 are two variables that stabilize
the division with a weak denominator. In our implementation,

I set α = 0.75, c1 = (0.01L)^2 and c2 = (0.03L)^2

where L is the dynamic range of the pixel values in the image.

---

So, this is my code

```
def custom_loss (y_true,y_pred):

M = 512           #M = total number of pixels in the sCT image
sum = 0

y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.int32)
y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32)
print(y_pred.shape)
print(y_true.shape)
y_pred = y_pred[0]
y_true = y_true[0]
for i in range(n):
    sum = sum+abs(y_true[i] - y_pred[i])
my_mae = sum / n
dssim = tf.reduce_mean((1 - tf.image.ssim(y_true,y_pred, max_val=512, 
filter_size=11,filter_sigma=1.5, k1=0.01, k2=0.03)) / 2)
my_mae = tf.cast(my_mae, tf.float32)

return (0.75*my_mae) + (1 - 0.75*dssim)
```

---

it have error when I run
`model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss= custom_loss,metrics=['accuracy'])`

error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/CRA01/Desktop/Unet/custom loss.py", line 85, in 
> history = model.fit(Training_CBCT_dataset,Training_pCT_dataset,validation_split=0.2,batch_size=1, epochs=5,  callbacks=[model_save_callback])
> File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
> File "C:\Users\CRA01\AppData\Local\Temp_*autograph_generated_fileqb1dimxg.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
> retval* = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
> ValueError: in user code:

```
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 893, in train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 539, in minimize
    return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 640, in apply_gradients
    grads_and_vars = optimizer_utils.filter_empty_gradients(grads_and_vars)
File "C:\Users\CRA01\miniconda3\envs\tf_2.9\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\utils.py", line 73, in filter_empty_gradients
    raise ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'conv2d_4/kernel:0', 'conv2d_4/bias:0', 'conv2d_5/kernel:0', 'conv2d_5/bias:0', 'conv2d_6/kernel:0', 'conv2d_6/bias:0', 'conv2d_7/kernel:0', 'conv2d_7/bias:0', 'conv2d_8/kernel:0', 'conv2d_8/bias:0', 'conv2d_9/kernel:0', 'conv2d_9/bias:0', 'conv2d_10/kernel:0', 'conv2d_10/bias:0', 'conv2d_11/kernel:0', 'conv2d_11/bias:0', 'conv2d_12/kernel:0', 'conv2d_12/bias:0', 'conv2d_13/kernel:0', 'conv2d_13/bias:0', 'conv2d_14/kernel:0', 'conv2d_14/bias:0', 'conv2d_15/kernel:0', 'conv2d_15/bias:0', 'conv2d_16/kernel:0', 'conv2d_16/bias:0', 'conv2d_17/kernel:0', 'conv2d_17/bias:0', 'conv2d_18/kernel:0', 'conv2d_18/bias:0', 'conv2d_19/kernel:0', 'conv2d_19/bias:0', 'conv2d_20/kernel:0', 'conv2d_20/bias:0', 'conv2d_21/kernel:0', 'conv2d_21/bias:0', 'conv2d_22/kernel:0', 'conv2d_22/bias:0', 'conv2d_23/kernel:0', 'conv2d_23/bias:0', 'conv2d_24/kernel:0', 'conv2d_24/bias:0', 'conv2d_25/kernel:0', 'conv2d_25/bias:0', 'conv2d_26/kernel:0', 'conv2d_26/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1, 32) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 32, 32) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_1/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_2/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 32, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_2/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_3/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_3/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_4/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_5/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_5/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_6/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_6/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_7/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 256, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_7/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_8/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 256, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_8/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_9/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 512, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_9/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_10/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 512, 1024) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_10/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_11/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1024, 1024) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_11/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_12/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1024, 2048) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_12/bias:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_13/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 2048, 2048) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_13/bias:0' shape=(2048,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_14/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3072, 1024) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_14/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_15/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1024, 1024) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_15/bias:0' shape=(1024,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_16/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 1536, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_16/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_17/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 512, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_17/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_18/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 768, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_18/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_19/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 256, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_19/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_20/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 384, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_20/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_21/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 128, 128) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_21/bias:0' shape=(128,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_22/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 192, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_22/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_23/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 64) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_23/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_24/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 96, 32) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_24/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_25/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 32, 32) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_25/bias:0' shape=(32,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_26/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 32, 1) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'conv2d_26/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>)).
```

Comment: `tf.cast` is not differentiable.

Comment: Avoid using `sum` as a variable name because it is a builtin function name. Also, you can compute the mean absolute error using `tf.reduce_mean`. Why do you do `y_pred = y_pred[0]` and `y_true = y_true[0]`, i.e. use only the first element of the batch?